# How to find rows whose column value has either a leading or trailing space

Tags: postgresql

How to find all rows whose column value has either a leading or trailing space (either single or multiple or just empty. I would like to filter all rows which has the above condition.

This is what I tried

```
select '"' || url || '"' from urls;
```

Comment: Please, [show us what you have tried](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) and where you are stuck.

Comment: @Stu thanks for your help, attached what I've tried but not sure how to filter

Comment: What is the point of `'"' || url || '"'`? How does that help with spaces? Filtering is done by a `WHERE` clause in SQL.

Comment: @Bergi appreciate if you can answer, just trying to be cynical doesn't help anyone

Comment: @user352290 Helping us understand your attempt will allow us to help you with a better explanation of what went wrong

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_name <> REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name, '^\s+|\s+$', '');

The above seems to work

Answer (score -1):

Postgres provides a full set on [String Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-string.html). Here use `length()` and `trim()`. `Trim()`, and companion functions `ltrim()` and `rtrim()`, remove any leading and/or trailing spaces. The `length()` function returns the number of characters/bytes in the string. So here select those rows where the length of the string is not the same as the length of the string with leading and trailing spaced removed.

```
select * 
  from <table_name> 
 where length(<column_name>) <> length(trim(<column_name>));
```